# LINQ ToList() serialization error?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, linq

I have a LINQ -> Class file named MoviesDB.dbml, I have added one table "Movie" to it, i have created a class "Movies" in which i have implemented inside all the methods.

Method GetAllMovies which gets a List, when binding the list i get the following:

```
Type 'DyMvWebsite.Movie' in Assembly 'DyMvWebsite, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' is not marked as serializable.
```

The code for the Method:

```
        public static List<Movie> GetAllMovies()
    {
        List<Movie> oMoviesList = new List<Movie>();

        using (MoviesDBDataContext oMoviesDBDataContext = new MoviesDBDataContext())
        {
            oMoviesList = oMoviesList.ToList<Movie>(); ;
        }

        return oMoviesList;
    }
```

After that i have tried putting the [Serializable] attribute in the "Movies" class and tried putting it in the linq designer file too, but same problem.

Edit:

After following what 'Massimiliano Peluso' suggested, i received a new error:

```
Type 'System.Data.Linq.ChangeTracker+StandardChangeTracker' in Assembly 'System.Data.Linq, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' is not marked as serializable.
```

Comment: Is your problem solved? The answer given below seems right.

Comment: No, i got a new error: I got a new error, Type 'System.Data.Linq.ChangeTracker+StandardChangeTracker' in Assembly 'System.Data.Linq, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' is not marked as serializable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this out

```
  MoviesDBDataContext.ObjectTrackingEnabled = false;
```

before firing the query.

If this still fails, then the work around will be create serializable  class similar to Movie class, and map the properties.

Answer (score 2):

Everything contained in the `Movie` class must be `Serializable` as well

*Apply the SerializableAttribute attribute to a type to indicate that instances of this type can be serialized. The common language runtime throws SerializationException if any type in the graph of objects being serialized does not have the SerializableAttribute attribute applied.
Apply the SerializableAttribute attribute even if the class also implements the ISerializable interface to control the serialization process.
All the public and private fields in a type that are marked by the SerializableAttribute are serialized by default, unless the type implements the ISerializable interface to override the serialization process. The default serialization process excludes fields that are marked with the NonSerializedAttribute attribute. If a field of a serializable type contains a pointer, a handle, or some other data structure that is specific to a particular environment, and cannot be meaningfully reconstituted in a different environment, then you might want to apply the NonSerializedAttribute attribute to that field.*

more info:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serializableattribute(v=VS.100).aspx

Comment: I have applied to the both the linq class "Movie" and the class "Movies" and still the same error, can i trace it somehow to know where is the cause, i have been struggling for ours on this ?

Comment: maybe movie contains a complex type which is not serializable(you have to implement  the ISerializable interface in this case) or it is not marked with [Serializable] attribute

Comment: I got a new error, Type 'System.Data.Linq.ChangeTracker+StandardChangeTracker' in Assembly 'System.Data.Linq, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' is not marked as serializable.

Comment: If your are using entity framework try using POCO's to decouple your EntityObjects from the change tracking in the data context
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2009/12/22/poco-proxies-part-1.aspx